# Command in same docker image work on CentOS 8 and fail with segfault on Debian 11

Tags: docker

docker build -t my_image

cat Dockerfile

```
FROM debian:7.11

COPY sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list
#RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 46925553

ENTRYPOINT [ "tail", "-f", "/dev/null" ]
```

cat sources.list

```
deb [trusted=yes] http://archive.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
```

docker run -d my_image

debian$docker exec -ti 15c213123 /bin/sh

```
#apt-key list

gpg: Segmentation fault caught ... exiting
Segmentation fault

#apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 46925553

Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring /tmp/tmp.HhlRvZl44h --trustdb-name /etc/apt//trustdb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d//debian-archive-jessie-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d//debian-archive-jessie-security-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d//debian-archive-jessie-stable.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d//debian-archive-squeeze-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d//debian-archive-squeeze-stable.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d//debian-archive-wheezy-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d//debian-archive-wheezy-stable.gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 46925553
gpg: requesting key 46925553 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: unnatural exit of external program
gpg: no handler for keyserver scheme `hkp'
gpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error
```

WTF?! my brain is broken. The same image on CentOS work well

centos$ docker exec -ti b9 /bin/sh

#apt-key list

```
...
-----------------------------------------------------------
pub   4096R/46925553 2012-04-27 [revoked: 2019-07-01]
uid                  Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (7.0/wheezy) <ftpmaster@debian.org>

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d//debian-archive-wheezy-stable.gpg
--------------------------------------------------------
...
```

debian$docker --version
Docker version 23.0.2, build 569dd73

centos$ docker --version
Docker version 20.10.18, build b40c2f6

image builded on centos tried on debian
image builded on debian tried on centos
the result is the same on CentOS work well, on Debian - fail

Comment: Btw, Debian provides the package `docker.io` (=20.10.5+dfsg1-1+deb11u2). Why choose to use upstream's `docker-ce` on Debian, but not same upstream on CentOS?

Comment: No difference  debian$ docker --version
Docker version 20.10.5+dfsg1, build 55c4c88
debian$ docker run -d my_image
79145942659f9a2924d04e72f06fcc52b9c4fd03876d52bc011dd646a295f2f1
debian$ docker exec -ti 791459426 /bin/sh
# apt-key list

gpg: Segmentation fault caught ... exiting
Segmentation fault